# AWS Cloudwatch Logs Stream to Amazon Elasticsearch Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm streaming CWL to Amazon Elasticsearch Service with Subscription.
The index was created automatically, but I want to change the number of shards.
I'm looking at a Lambda function, but I can't find any code that specifies the number of shards.

Also, how can I make the index look like cwl-{logGroup Title}-00001?

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

To have the index with logGroup title you can use below code:

At Line 62 of the Lambda function you will see the following section of code:

```
// index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
var indexName = [
'cwl-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // cwl + time
('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
].join('.');
```

Replace it with the following code:

```
// index name format: cwl-log-group-YYYY.MM.DD
var indexName = [
'cwl-' + payload.logGroup.toLowerCase().split('/').join('-') + '-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // cwl + log group + time
('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
].join('.');
```

This change will create a separate index for each log group. Please test the same in your testing environment first before deploying in production.

For changing the number of shards, you can create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) at AWS ES end for this specific index pattern.